# Reach array from another view controller

Tags: xcode, swift

So I have 2 view controllers: "SpillereViewController" and "HovedViewController".

In "SpillereViewController" i have an array that looks like this below:

```
var mineSpillere = ["1", "2"]
```

How can i reach that array in the other view controller named "HovedViewController"?

Comment: create a same property in the HovedViewController and pass mineSpillere to that class.

Comment: @Amit89 - What is a "same property"?

Answer (score 0):

Create a proprty in the class `HovedViewController` like:

```
class HovedViewController {

     var mineSpillere = [String]()
}
```

in `SpillereViewController` class

```
class SpillereViewController {
    var mineSpillere = ["1", "2"]

    func assignArray() {
        let obj = HovedViewController()
        obj.mineSpillere = self.mineSpillere
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use delegate.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass your array to your destination view controller which is HovedViewController in your case. Go and define a array in your HovedViewController and add a segue give a segue identifier name so you can use prepareForSegue method pass your array.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue?, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue!.identifier == "toHovedViewController" {
        let viewController: HovedViewController = segue!.destinationViewController as ViewController
        viewController.destionationArray = array

    }

}
```